# delete the record based on ID in one table if all the records of same Id's deleted in another table

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

pls help me with logic.
I have two tables of customers and transactions and there is column action I, U, D. If column action is I or U upsert the data if it is D delete the data in transactions tables.If all records of same transaction id are deleted then delete customers record else delete the transactions record

We can do insert,upsert,delete using Update strategy in transaction table but how can we delete the customer record if the same transaction IDs deleted

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a logic ( like you said ) to delete from customer table. And its safer to either create a new pipeline in same mapping or a brand new mapping.

So, you will read customer_key from customer, do a lookup into transaction table(condition on customer_key), if you see no row found, delete that customer.

1. Read all customer_key from customer table.
2. Lookup on transaction table on customer_key. return customer_key.
3. Use update strategy, link customer_key from SQ #1 and customer_key from lookup. create a condition like this
   `IIF ( lkp_customer_key is null, DD_DELETE)`
4. Link customer_key from SQ #1 to the customer target.

You can do this using left join too in source qualifier as well.

Answer (score 0):

most of database servers on delete, it cascade the update on respective tables